# automate Mail so it can run a shell script when a specific message is received

Tags: macos, automation

I am trying to see if there is a way to get this done: Basically I get email from a server at specific intervals, so I am trying to run a shell script that will perform an install of a specific package on my mac when the mail arrives.

I do not have access to the server so I cannot do anything on it; I can only rely on the fact that at an undetermined time during the day, I will get the email and I will need to install a package. I am doing it by hand but it is tedious honestly, and prone to error if I am not checking the email for any reason.

I was thinking to use Applescript, but if there is any other way to do this via console or shell script, I would be more happy honestly (never been a great fan of Applescript).

Is there any way to accomplish this task? I don't even understand if mail on OSX is scriptable. I've looked around but I've found only Automator links. I know Python as scripting language, if that can be used in any way with Mail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit preferences in Mail, select the Rules tab.  One of the actions is to run an AppleScript.  You could have the AppleScript fire off a shell script if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! I will have to try to see if I can fire that event just using the pre-build rules in Mail. The email that I receive may have a different sender, and the title changes based on the day, so I will have to find some sort of consistent data to see if  I can get the script to fire exactly every day when I get the mail (some times I get more than one per day). Thanks!

Comment: That's the problem with rules - ya gotta have something consistant to trigger them :)  you might have to set up more than one rule.. just be sure to include a "stop processing rules" action in each one so you dont get your script triggered more than once.

Comment: You may also choose to have every mail message trigger the script and have your script (which should have much better parsing [eg. regex, string manipulation] capabilities) decide which messages it should process.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I just wish that there was a way to access mail without going trough applescript; in that way I could just use shell command like sed to filter exactly what I need and not being chained to what mail expose, rule-wise.

At least I have a place where to start :)

Comment: another option would be to skip the mail app and write your own pop3/imap client (python and mono should be easy to write this in) that just scanned for these particular mail messages.

Comment: That sounds a bit over my actual skill level :) I would be able maybe to parse whatever format mail uses to store the messages, if I could find how it actually works (and if anyone wrote libraries for parsing these files), but writing a whole imap client is something that I think is a bit too much for a person like me, with no real knowledge about how a mail client works :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23395/discussion-between-dan-o-and-newbiez)